# Como desenvolver um jogo básico usando opengl que aceite comandos do teclado

Tags: c, c++, opengl, jogos

Tentei seguir o fonte de um tutorial [Metar Gearn Nanna](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=429), pois tinha interesse em criar um jogo em opengl e c++, podia ser algo simples, com validações precárias, apenas para eu entender o conceito, aprendi a desenhar triangulos e colorir usando o opengl (confesso que poderia ter dedidado um pouco tempo e esforço para essa tarefa), mas ficou muito longe de conseguir fazer um jogo como o snake por exemplo. O link com o fonte estava quebrado. E o meu conhecimento nessa área é extremamente limitado, quase nulo, [segui essa apostila](http://www.brunoevangelista.com/wp-content/uploads/2004/01/opengl2006_course.pdf), mas também tive dificuldade. 
Acredito que criar um jogo seja algo de interesse de muitos desenvolvedores por hobby mesmo, mas muitos como eu acabam encontrando muitas dificuldade. A falta de código de exemplo de algo funcional foi algo que me limitou bastante. Não postei código pelo motivo de eu não saber muito bem nem por onde começar.
 
 Então o questão real a dessa pergunta é: Como fazer um jogo em opengl (qualquer jogo) que aceite interação do usuário (teclas do teclado, mouse ou controle)?
 O que eu espero como resposta são coisas do tipo links com exemplo de código, documentação e etc... qualquer coisa que seja útil não só para mim, mas para todos que tenham interesse em construir um jogo. Não importa que seja simples. Se  tiver um menu e um quadro que ande com as setas do mouse está valendo! A ideia é dar um norte para todos que quererem desenvolver um jogo leiam essa pergunta e com a resposta sejam capazes de dar os primeiros passos.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54223/discussion-on-question-by-sileno-brito-como-desenvolver-um-jogo-basico-usando-op)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trabalhando com openGL e C++ para criar um jogo você precisará programar ele bem baixo nível mesmo, digo isso pelo modo de tratar colisões e algumas outras funcionalidade por exemplo, é mais trabalhoso porém é muito prazeroso fazer do zero e ver o resultado final. Se aprende muito com isso.

Eu fiz um experimento em C++ uma vez criando um joguinho bobo só para testar colisões e movimentos, comentei o máximo que pude. [De uma olhada no repositório do meu jogo no github](https://github.com/guilouro/jogo-experimento-opengl).. acho que pegando um exemplo e tentando entender o que cada coisa faz facilita muita no aprendizado.

> [Link para o repositório](https://github.com/guilouro/jogo-experimento-opengl/)

O arquivo `main.cpp` é onde eu fiz o jogo e a pasta `resources` é onde eu coloquei as libs que usei no projeto.

Comment: Com certeza vou ver parabéns pela iniciativa, assim que eu ler te posto uma resposta vou tentar ser o mais breve.

Comment: Legal!! Qualquer dúvida coloque ai para a gente debater!!

Comment: Não executei ainda, só li o código do main pelo github. Seu código está limpo, bem organizado e fácil de entender.